# SSID's Not Separating Computers on Network

Tags: networking, wireless-router, links, ssid

Before I started to "improve" my wireless network, I had a working network with wired and wireless capability.  I connect my PCs via a wired connections and share all folders between each PCs.  My tablet and smartphone connect to the internet via a wireless connection on the router.  This system had only 1 SSID

Recently I learned my router could handle up to four SSIDs.  I was told that a I could isolate my PCs and associated folders and files from snooping eyes if I set up a second SSID just for guests.

Thus, I proceeded to set up two separate wireless networks -- one for me (SSID=Private)and the second for guests(SSID=Guest).  Each SSID has a unique password. I want the Guest for anyone who visits including my granddaughter.

I have a Century Link Router (Zyxel PK5001Z).  I configured two separate SSIDs with different passwords.  I decided to take my laptop, disconnect it from the LAN and use it to test my security.  I logged onto the Guest wireless network.  I expected to not be able to see my folders and files from my Guest wireless connection.  However, from that laptop connected to the Guest wireless, I can see everything that I can when connected to the LAN via a wired connection.

Can someone suggest what else I need to do to isolate the Guest Wireless from my Private Network?

Comment: Did you check if your router actually supports WiFi isolation, and that it's enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple SSID's only allow you to have multiple 'names' for your network; I couldn't see anything [from the specs](http://www.zyxel.com/us/en/products_services/pk5001z.shtml?t=p) that indicated that you can enable SSID isolation mode, the only thing I could find was to allow the router to [separate the subnets](http://internethelp.centurylink.com/internethelp/modem-pk5001z-wireless-multiple-ssid.html), which will 'sort of' achieve what you want by saying users of network 'Private' will be on block 192.168.0.1-100 (or whatever) and users of 'Guest' will be on 192.168.0.102-253 (or whatever). It only 'logically' separates the networks, meaning anyone who is on your WiFi could manually edit their IP and still get to your 'Private' network. Isolation mode is supposed to make it so that network 'Private' and 'Guest' could have the same IP's and not be able to communicate between each other without another router (or extra routing configurations). With your current hardware configuration there are ways to achieve sort of what you want, but require more explanation than the scope of this question and in the end you might still be better just getting a better WiFi router :/